# Is there a way to condense "put back" into one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

The example in question involves a sentence of the structure:

> I'm putting my changes back.

Is there a one-word equivalent for "put ... back"? E.g.:

> I'm ______ing my changes.

Comment: Reverting, restoring, returning, rolling-back?

Comment: ... postponing?

Comment: Yes. Use "revert" as in `git revert <commit>`.

Comment: undo, return, rollback

Comment: As Robusto says, definitely *revert* wrt to changes, but perhaps *replace* with respect to things like objects on shelves.

Comment: Undo, reverse, and revert are the most common words that satisfy your requirements.  They are very commonly used in technology interfaces, as Robusto has shown above, which are becoming more and more ubiquitous.

Comment: "put back" as in timing = postpone or delay; or "put back" as in "revert, amend, undo"?

Comment: @Alex W , it also depends on the technology. If it is revert on github, it is rollback in relational databases, undo in a code or text processor, restore in file backups, etc.

Comment: Restoring and rollbacking my changes sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say *Revert*, as it is clearer that you're returning to a previous state, as opposed to *Reverse*, which from the formal definition implies an opposite condition, not simply the past condition (but from common usage I'm familiar with, I'd say is nearly interchangeable with *revert).* (As an aside, see the interesting case of the noun of *revert*; possibly implying a return to what can be seen as an original state?)

*Undo* is also a good choice; and to me, it's nearly synonymous with *Revert*, even though the formal definition says it's not quite a reverting of something to a previous state.

And, see other answers; these words have more subtle meanings and usage in different contexts, such as in the information technology world.

**Revert**

> intransitive verb:
>
> 1: to come or go back (as to a former condition,
>   period, or subject)
>
> 2 : to return to the proprietor or his or her
>   heirs at the end of a reversion
>
> 3 : to return to an ancestral type
>
> noun:
>
> a person who has converted to the Islamic faith.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revert

**Reverse**

> adjective
>
> 1 a :  opposite or contrary to a previous or normal condition
>
> b (1) :  having the back presented to the observer or opponent
>   (2) :  made with one's back to the basketball net
>
> 2 : coming from the rear of a military force
>
> 3 : acting, operating, or arranged in a manner contrary to the usual
>
> 4 : effecting reverse movement
>
> 5 : so made that the part which normally prints in color appears white
>   against a colored background

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reverse

**Undo**

> transitive verb
>
> 1 :  to open or loose by releasing a fastening
>
> 2 :  to make of no effect or as if not done :  make null :  reverse
>
> 3
>   a :  to ruin the worldly means, reputation, or hopes of 
>   b :  to disturb the composure of :  upset 
>   c :  seduce 3

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undo

Answer (score 2):

"undo" comes to mind.  "**I'm undoing my changes**"  (whatever changes you mean)

- You can't undo the past.
- The damage cannot be undone.
- It's impossible to undo the suffering caused by the earthquake.
- Can you help me undo the shoelace?

> - undo - (verb) "to make of no effect or as if not done :  make null, reverse" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undo)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're talking about programming or writing and, specifically, a situation involving version control or document control. In this situation, the definition of *revert* is very specific: you're changing your code so that it matches what is in the repository, essentially undoing your work.

However, it sounds like you committed a set of changes and they were reverted in another commit, they never got merged with the specified branch, or something like that. In such a case, I would *reintroduce* my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on context .... what is the nature of the change being "put back"?

However, a few possibilities offhand are

"undoing"

"rolling back".  For example rolling back a database transaction.

"turning back"

"rejecting" (particularly if the change must be accepted or approved before it takes effect)

"overturning"

"revoking"

"retracting"

"rescinding"   (usually an action by a higher authority)

"deleting"

"quashing"   (the literal meaning is to suppress)

"cancelling"

"repeal"

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Peter. We generally discourage long list answers like this, and we are looking for you to cite authoritative sources with insightful commentary.